# Json to DataTable for Google Visualization wrong output

Tags: javascript, php, json, csv, google-visualization

I am trying to create a chart using Google Visualization from a CSV. I have parsed the CSV file using PHP and output the data I require as Json. To be specific, Column 1 contains dates formatted as "*dd/mm/yyyy*" and Column 2 contains prices formatted to 2 d.p. just as below:

```
[["Date","Close"],
["29\/01\/1985","1,292.62"],
["30\/01\/1985","1,287.88"],
["31\/01\/1985","1,286.77"],

...

["30\/04\/2015","17,840.52"],
["01\/05\/2015","18,024.06"]]
```

As you can see above, the code contains headings named "*Date*" and "*Close*". I have two files, one containing the Json code named "*json.php*" and the second called "*chart.php*" containing the script which calls the Json code through Ajax. The code from the second file looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Google Chart</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1','packages':['annotationchart']}]}"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
      google.load('visualization', '1', {
          'packages': ['annotationchart']
      });
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
          var jsonData = $.ajax({
              url: "json.php",
              dataType: "json",
              async: false
          }).responseText;
          var array  = JSON.parse(jsonData);
          var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(array);
          var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotationChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
          var options = {
          displayAnnotations: true
        };

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="chart" style="width: 900px; height 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is, once I execute the script and refresh the site, the chart does not appear instead I get an error that the data must have at least have two columns. I placed the data directly into the div using:

```
document.getElementById("chart").innerHTML = data;
```

And what appears to happen is that the Json code is not converted into DataTable and instead shows:

```
[object Object]
```

I tried placing the Json code directly into the DataTable without converting it into an array before using:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
```

And still the output is the same, `[object Object]` appears. I went back and placed the data received from the call directly into the div and the Json appears just as it should. The problem seems to be the conversion into the DataTable, and I've got no clue of why. Really grateful for any hint. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have some issues here.

1. When you have `dataType : 'json'` then `JSON.parse` is redundant. `JSON.parse` is for parsing a string *into* JSON.
2. You need to define som datatypes in `date` and `number` format in order to create an AnnotationChart. Google cannot guess which columns and which data is what. It need to have the columns specified and the data delivered in a proper format according to the columns datatype.
3. The data in the JSON is not in a proper format itself. The dates cannot be parsed right away, and the numbers would be parsed as strings.

So forget about JSON.parse and a magic JSON -> array -> appropriate DataTable the AnnotationChart is able to use. Do this instead :

```js
var row, date, data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
data.addColumn('number', 'Close');
for (var i=1;i<jsonData.length;i++) {
    row = jsonData[i];
    date = row[0].split('/');
    data.addRow([
        new Date(date[2], date[1], date[0]), 
        parseFloat(row[1])
    ]);
}
```

your code from the question in a fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/mvjcff8c/**

Comment: Wow!! Works like a charm. It makes sense to me now that data always has to be formatted correctly, in this case with a javascript loop. Thanks so much!!

Comment: sorry to bug you once again. I tested the scenario over and over again in JSFiddle and it works fine. Once I implement the code in my localhost and process the script, everything works smoothly up to the point when the graph appears and shows the error "_undefined is not a function_". I tried eliminating the column headers and placing `i=0` instead of `i=1` and nothing happens. Any suggestions? Best regards!!

Comment: No worries. The problem was `var jsonData` as it could not be processed correctly. The solution was to parse it first and then pass the data into the function using `var jsonData = JSON.parse(json);`